# hybridauth thirdparty Facebook autoload failed opening laravel after composer install

Tags: php, facebook, symfony, laravel-4, hybridauth

I used composer to install hybridauth in my laravel 4 application.
When i tried to get user profile with facebook provider :

```
$userProfile = $provider->getUserProfile();
```

I have this error :

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
>   Hybrid_Providers_Facebook::initialize(): Failed opening required
>   '...laravel/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/thirdparty/Facebook/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.../laravel/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib:.:/usr/local/php5.6/lib/php')

It seems like thirdparty/Facebook/autoload.php is required but I didn't have this autoload file in the directory. Is it a problem with the composer install?

my thirdparty file :

- LinkedIn
- OAuth
- OpenID
- index.html

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version you are using is not as straight forward as the previous versions.
You do need to get the Facebook API from https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk first.
Then extract to the "third party" folder. You only need the folder that contains all the Facebook API files and folders. Examples for files: autoload.php, facebook.php, etc.... and it's folders including "Authentication", "Exceptions", etc....
Structure will be  `"hybridauth\Hybrid\thirdparty\Facebook"`

Comment: Thanks a lot! it's ok now!

Comment: Do you know the others API url to extract in the "third party" folder for Google, Twitter and Twitch? or a place where i can find that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello Irtiza, do you know the others API url to extract in the "third party" folder for Google, Twitter and Twitch? or a place where i can find that? Thank you in advance. Irtiza

Comment: Dear @Matthieu most of them are available in "hybridauth\hybridauth\additional-providers" folder other you can place in same "hybridauth\hybridauth\hybridauth\Hybrid\thirdparty" directory. I used this for CAKEPHP and it's working fine for me.Sorry for late reply.